# How can ask professional for forwarding my e-mail to person who is responsible for purchases?

Tags: professionalism, communication, email, contracts, relationships

I try to expand my distribution network. I have big database with potential companies. For some of them I know who is responsible for purchases but for most of them I have just e-mail of sales department or just an info e-mail of company. 
How can ask professional for forwarding my e-mail to person who is responsible for purchases?

Thank is advance

Comment: Did you try  purchasing@potenialcompany.com?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get your email forwarded to the purchasing person by just asking. If the company is large enough to have a purchasing department, they will generally publicize this address. If it's just a person who makes decisions among the rest of their job duties, they generally don't want email from people who know nothing about them, but got their name from a database of contact information, or worse, got a random other person's name from a database of contact information.

If the product you are trying to sell is compelling, and your email reaches someone who wants it, that person will get in touch with purchasing themselves as a way to end up owning your product. If it's not, they will delete your email no matter how you ask them to send it to the person you want to reach.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Workplace Stack Exchange, Irina. Your question does not fall within the scope of this site, however I'll still give answering it a shot.

Try calling the company and asking to be passed to the purchaser / purchasing department. Establishing that connection and asking for their e-mail in person is going to improve the odds of that person actually reading your communication when they receive it.

However, if all you have are various company e-mails, simply politely ask for your e-mail to be forwarded:

> **Subject:** **[Company Name Here]** - Purchasing Department - **[Your Text Here]**
>
> To Whom It May Concern,
>
> This communication is meant for the purchasing department. Would you be so kind as to forward it to them on my behalf?
>
> Dear Purchaser,
>
> My apologies for contacting you with no advance notice, however I have the following opportunity to offer you ... .... ...

Keep in mind that many places may simply consider your e-mail to be spam and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to put this politely.

E-mailing a random person and asking to be passed to purchasing virtually guarantees your being blocked as a spammer.

If you want to talk to Purchasing, it is *your* job to do the research to find their contact info. If you can't be bothered to do so, you are too lazy to be worth doing business with. If you csn't figure out how to do so, you are too clueless to be worth doing business with.